# I need to design below is any idea its highly appreciate?

Tags: apex, visualforce, lightning-web-components

[image]Need to design attached page need idea for this it is possible using LWC and another method we have in salesforce?

Comment: Yes, you can easily write this. Where are you having problems with this?

Answer (score 1):

You could use a lightning datatable with row numbers:
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-datatable

For the last column you could use the lightning checkbox group:
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-checkbox-group/example

Hope it helps! :)